# Getting #stream as an output in Drracket

Tags: stream, scheme, racket

Streams of order and data are given and I need to order the data according to the `order-stream`.

```
#lang racket
(define the-empty-stream '())
(define (stream-car stream)
 (car stream))
(define-syntax cons-stream
 (syntax-rules ()
    ((cons-stream x y)
     (cons x (delay y)))))

(define (stream-cdr stream)
 (force (cdr stream)))
(define stream-null? null?)
(define (integers-starting-from n)
 (stream-cons n (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))

(define integers (integers-starting-from 1))

(define order-stream (stream-cons 2 1))
(define data-stream (stream-cons 5 6))

(define (reorder order-stream data-stream)
 (cond ((stream-null? order-stream) the-empty-stream)
       ((stream-null? data-stream) the-empty-stream)
       (else (stream-cons (stream-ref data-stream 
                                      (stream-car order-stream))
                          (reorder (stream-cdr order-stream) data-stream)))))
```

When I execute `(reorder order-stream data-stream)` I get `#stream` as output instead of `6 . #promise`. This is my programming assignment so instead of giving complete code please give some hints instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what you have:

```
(define (reorder order-stream data-stream)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 (cond ((stream-null? order-stream) the-empty-stream)
       ((stream-null? data-stream) the-empty-stream)
       (else (stream-cons (stream-ref data-stream 
                                      (stream-car order-stream))
                          (reorder (stream-cdr order-stream) data-stream)))))
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

(define (stream-cdr stream)
 (force (cdr stream)))
```

what kind of thing `(stream-cdr stream)` is expected to return?

and then you're calling

```
(define order-stream (cons-stream 2 1))
```

What is `order-stream`'s `cdr`?

---

Stream programming is fun. For instance, to calculate partial sums of a stream, `p-s [a,b,c...] = a, a+b, a+b+c, ...`, we can write

```
(define (partial-sums xs init)
    (cons-stream init 
         (partial-sums (stream-cdr xs)
                       (+ (stream-car xs) init))))
```

We can easily abstract away the `+` as a general binary operation argument:

```
(define (scanl + xs init)
    (cons-stream init 
              (scanl + (stream-cdr xs)
                       (+ (stream-car xs) init))))
```

and call it as, e.g.

```
(define factorials (scanl * integers 1))
```

Another, *interesting* way to define `scanl`, is

```
(define (scanlist + xs init)
   (define rs (cons-stream init 
                (combine-streams + xs rs)))
   rs)
```

Writing `combine-streams` (a.k.a. `zipWith` in Haskell) is a straightforward deal.

In Racket, be sure to work in full language, where `define` is recursive, analogous to `letrec` (not `let`), or else the last one won't work (can you see why?).

Comment: Order-stream is a stream of numbers like 2 3 4 1.... those number are the order for the data-stream for example like 5 6 7 8 ... output will be 6 7 8 1.. which is reordered form ...... so the cdr of order-stream is 3 for this case

Comment: no, it's not, as written. `(cons-stream 2 1) = (cons 2 (delay 1)) = '(2 . 1)`. this is _not_ a stream. `(cons 2 (delay the-empty-stream))` is a stream: its `stream-cdr` _is a stream_. `1` is _not_ a stream. look at the definition of `reorder`. the highlighted fragments say that `stream-cdr` of a stream **must**  be a stream.

Comment: Oh i get it now my definition of the reorder is right but the stream i created is wrong and can u also show me the way to create stream containing more elements. Using cons seems more tedious .. thank you for your help have a good day

Comment: yes, just write yourself a function `list-to-stream`. it's easy. to create an infinite stream, make some specialized function, like `integers-from-by x d = x, x+d, x+d+d, ...`; also popular are `partial-sums` (or abstract the `+` as general operation argument), and Haskell's `iterate f x = x, f(x), f(f(x)), ...`. Consider upvoting, and accepting the answer that helped you the most. :) accepting gives you +2 rep, and at rep 15 you are able to upvote answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Racket has a built-in `stream-cons`, which you're accidentally calling, instead of `cons-stream` as you intended to use.

Comment: when i use cons-stream i get error like 
stream-ref: contract violation
  expected: stream?
  given: '(5 . #<promise:...Desktop/answer2a.scm:8:13>)

Comment: @sageArt you didn't make the replacement fully throughout your code. but there are other problems.